# How to read and parse data from file?

Tags: java

My Task is to read some data from file, split it and then parse it to correct instance of class. So far so good, but I have a problem with the class `Education`, because every person has different education degree, so I don't know how to check that. The same problem comes with `Insurance` class, because for every person we have information for different period of time. So that is my problem basicaly.

I don't know how many instances of `Education` I have to create.

Here are two examples of the data that I have to read and parse:

```
--1--
"Plamen;Stoichev;Izmirliev;M;16.7.1980;206;Bulgaria;Sofiya;Studentski;1016;Opalchenska;21;;;P; William Gladstoine;15.9.1986;15.6.1993;S;William Gladstoine ;15.9.1993;30.6.1998;3.343;B; William Gladstoine;1.10.1999;1.6.2003;3.045" +
"2016;11;1015.20;2016;10;605.93;2016;9;701.61;2016;7;981.86;2016;4;1042.57;2016;3;919.87;2016;2;720.00;2015;12;969.75;2015;6;641.16;2015;3;811.76;2015;2;757.07;2014;12;1321.31;2014;11;863.39;2014;9;1539.51;2014;7;1159.62;2014;5;1295.59;2014;3;910.59;2014;1;1033.80";

--2--
Violeta;Konstantinova;Orlova;F;23.8. 1982;148;Bulgaria;Sofia;Izgrev;1008;King Boris III;123;5;26;P;William Gladstoine ;15.9.1988;15.6.1995;S;William Gladstoine ;15.9.1995;30.6.2000;4.069
2016;11;1587.70;2016;8;1524.04;2016;6;1273.10;2016;4;1129.08; 2016;2;1469.79;2015;12;927.91;2015;10;1116.83;2015;6;1143.05;2015;4;1348.82;
```

The `SocialInsuranceRecord` class has three parameters `year`, `month`, `tax amount`.
The `Education` class has `level of degree`, `name of school`, `enrollment date`, `graduation date`, `average grade`;

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import DataObjects.address.Address;
import DataObjects.education.Education;
import DataObjects.insurance.SocialInsuranceRecord;
import DataObjects.personaldetails.Citizen;
import DataObjects.personaldetails.Gender;

public class GetDataFromFile {
    private List<Citizen> citizents = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String FILE_PATH = "D:\\data.dat";

    public List<Citizen> getCitizens() {
        List<Citizen> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(FILE_PATH))));
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                Citizen citizen = parseCitizent(scanner.nextLine());
                list.add(citizen);
            }

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public Citizen parseCitizent(String nextLine) {
        String[] split = nextLine.split("\\s*;");

        Citizen citizen = new Citizen(split[0], split[1], split[2], Gender.valueOf(split[3]), LocalDate.parse(split[4]), Integer.parseInt(split[5]));       
        Address address = new Address(split[6], split[7], split[8], split[9], split[10], split[11], Integer.parseInt(split[11]), Integer.parseInt(split[12]));
        citizen.setAddress(address);
        List<Education> educations = new ArrayList<>();
        // to do...
        citizen.set_educations(educations);
        List<SocialInsuranceRecord> socilInsuranceRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        // to do...
        citizen.set_socialInsuranceRecords(socilInsenter code hereuranceRecords);
        return citizen;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you already know how to read data.

Comment: Could you just give the education format ? What should it look like ? Do you have the hand on that format ?

Comment: If you want to work with csv data, this data must follow a format (predefined number of columns).

Comment: Well, I know the basics, but this is more complicated, because I don't know how many instances of class Education and class  Insurance needs to be created.